# Angularjs - set value if div has class

Tags: angularjs

I want to set a index value, if div has class  'active'

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
```

Something like this:

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1" ng-class="(this).hasClass('active')?$index = 1: ''">
```

Not sure how to approach this.

Comment: What is `$index` here?

Comment: @dfsq $index is just the value i want to  set if div contains class 'active'

Comment: Don't know why you need it, but you can achive it by writing custom directive.

Comment: I did not understand why you need it. If you tell us what you are trying to do in general, maybe we will suggest a better approach

Comment: @JohnyStark Depending on the active div i want to the index to be set, so that i can run different function. I am making a wizard and each step requires different function to be run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I far as I can understand you want the set scope property indicating the index of the active tab. In this case if the tab `#tab1` is selected then `$scope.$index` should be `1`, etc.

Since reading class attribute means manupilations with DOM the best place for this functionality is custom directive. It's pretty convinient that directives can be bound to class names ([`restrict: 'C'`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-restrict-)). Then the naive implementation could be:

```
app.directive('active', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.tabIndex = element[0].id.replace('tab', '');
        }
    };
});
```

Note, that I set `tabIndex` property in order not to confuse it with `ngRepeat` `$index` variable.

Here is a little demo of this approach: **http://plnkr.co/edit/y6Mj4kFCq2fS5VdCjSsb?p=preview**